# Javscript / Cloud Firestore Query: Need to store data in array and get it out for use. Need for Google Charts to populate the datatable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Need help ... i am unable to populate this array                           unarr.push(querySnapshot.size);
to get the number of users per district to create the chart. 
New to javascript, hence may be missing something very trivial. Can someone help to fix this?

```
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

  db.collection("district").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'District Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Users');
    data.addRows([['Mushrooms', 3]]);
    var dtarr = [];
    dtarr = snapshotToArray(querySnapshot);
    var unarr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(
            function(doc) {
              db.collection("users").where("district", "==", doc.id).get().then(
              function(querySnapshot) {
                      // this output  to stored and returned to unarr[] array object
                      alert(querySnapshot.size);
                      unarr.push(querySnapshot.size);
              });
            });
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < dtarr.length; i++) {data.addRows([[dtarr[i],unarr[i]]]);}
   // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'District wise split of registered user', 'height':500};
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
  }
</script>
```